# How to change Sprite layer in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

How to change Sprite's layer during runtime in andengine Scene?

Comment: have you tried deattaching the sprite from the layer and attaching it to the layer you wish the sprite to be?

Comment: yes i have tried it but changine the like this will cause jittery feel.

Comment: i've the same problem, any solution?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you understand by changing layer. If you mean z index of entity, then you can use [entity.setZIndex(int)](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/Entity.java#183) and you need to call [parent.sortChildren()](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/Entity.java#535) manually on the parent of your sprite.

If by changing layer you mean detaching from one parent and attaching to another parent, then that is another problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have been recently working on this issue. It is frustrating maintaining the zorder of sprites using sortChidren and setZOrder, especially if you have a complex arrangment of layers(Scene Entitys).

I found that adding this override to every Entity derived layer you have.

```
@Override
protected void onDrawChildren(GL10 pGL, Camera pCamera) {
    getParent().sortChildren();
    super.onDrawChildren(pGL, pCamera);
}
```

This lets you set the Z order sprite.setZOrder(order++) and you are guaranteed your entity's a drawn in the sprite order you have set at least.

I'm guessing this adds quite a bit of overhead, but I don't notice on my galaxy ace. (yet to try profiling it)

The problem is that when you call setZOrder(...) you need to call sortChildren after attaching every subsequent sprite/entity added to the parent, otherwise any higher zorder entity will get drawn over by newly added entities as the setZOrder does not actually set the z axis of the 3d object. Only the order in which the object is drawn. (all andengine objects have the same z axis value regardless of the mZIndex value in Entity)
Hence you must sort the children whenever a new entity is added to the parent entity.

This is what I have so far. Please correct me if I'm wrong or have any better solutions.

Comment: but now i think overriding `attachChild()` and doing it there instead would be way more efficient.